# Разница между "Зачем он это сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал это?"

Tags: значения

Есть ли смысловая разница между "Зачем он это сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал это?"

Answer (score 13):

В русском языке слово, на которое приходится смысловое/логическое ударение, как правило переносится в конец фразы. Таким образом

Вопрос 1 ставится к сказуемому - зачем сделал.

Вопрос 2 ставится к дополнению - зачем сделал именно это, а не что-то другое.

Answer (score 3):

**Общие положения**

1. В повествовательном предложении нейтральной тональности (без логических ударений) **тоническое ударение действительно падает на конец фразы.**

Стандартное предложение состоит из двух фраз, **восходящего и нисходящего тона** (повышение тона – пауза – понижение тона), например: *Завтра Утром // мы поедем в пАрк*.

(Тоническое ударение может **смещаться с конца фразы** только при логическом выделении отдельных слов).

2. Немного иначе строится **вопросительное предложение,** например: *Мы завтра поедем в парк?*

В этом случае логическое ударение падает на то слово, к которому относится вопрос. (Логическое ударение – это тоническое ударение с дополнительным усилением голоса).

В приведенном предложении ударение может падать **на любое из четырех слов:** мы или кто? завтра или в другой день? поедем или не поедем? в парк или еще куда?

После повышение тона на нужном слове голос остается на том же уровне, то есть не понижается в конце фразы (это отличительное свойство **вопросительной интонации**).

**Решение задачи**

Не имеет смысла проводить анализ предложения, если **неясна речевая ситуация,** поэтому представим такой диалог.

Петя толкнул Машу. Учитель спрашивает:

– ЗачЕм //ты это сделал?  Почему ты всё время обижаешь Машу?

– Я не хотел её обижать.

– Зачем же ты //сдЕлал это?

В обозначенной ситуации  по смыслу мы можем выделить **два слова**: или само действие (сделал), или его цель (зачем).

Структура предложений при этом **перестраивается** так, чтобы было удобно сделать повышение тона на нужном слове.

**Таким образом, ответ такой.** Разная структура предложений позволяет наилучшим образом выделить логическим ударением то слово, к которому относится вопрос, а это разные слова (сделал, зачем).

Comment: wow, you are good!

Answer (score 1):

В данном конкретном примере, imho, смысловой разницы никакой. Первый вариант общеупотребительный, второй - поэтический.

В других случаях, например "Зачем он подлость сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал подлость?" все наоборот - второй вариант общеупотребительный, первый - поэтический. Различные слова имеют различные традиции употребления.

И наконец в третьих случаях, когда оба порядка чередования вполне употребительны в обычной речи (напр. "Зачем он скворечник сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал скворечник?") , я поддержу ответ @Баян Купи-ка.