# Разница между "Раз семь" и "Семь раз"?

Tags: значения

Я хорошо помню ответы из [Разница между "Зачем он это сделал?" и "Зачем он сделал это?"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/18121/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be)

В данном случае не все выглядит так однозначно ( для меня ). По-прежнему, вопрос в том, есть ли смысловая разница, и, если да, то какая.

Answer (score 9):

Семь раз - это конкретное указание на число раз чего-либо (что-то происходило семь раз, а не восемь, четыре, одиннадцать). А раз семь - это примерно, приблизительно. То есть, никто не считал точно, было семь раз или шесть.

Comment: аналогично напр., ***часа (на, через) два***, ***сантиметра (на, через) три*** и т.п.